# What are good resources for learning more about communications?

Tags: radio-communications, phraseology, literature-recommendation

As title says, which book/web site/etc.. are available for learning proper communication (for Private Pilot License)?

Comment: Which jurisdiction?

Comment: @vasin1987 why [tag:easa-regulations]?

Comment: what is PPL? Play Background Music?

Comment: @Him PPL = Private Pilot License around these parts.

Comment: @DeltaLima his profile says he from slovenia. I wikipedia it and its member of EU hence easa-regs.

Comment: [Phraseology](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=phraseology+atc+filetype:pdf)?

Comment: @DeltaLima thx.

Comment: @vasin1987 that makes some sense. However, 99% of the phraseology in the world is agreed upon by ICAO. Individual states may file their local differences from the ICAO standard phraseology in their own AIP. Some European states do. This is outside the powers of EASA.

Comment: I do not see why this has been closed. We have other questions asking for resources and those have been well received. What makes this one different?

Comment: I've found 4 similar questions that are still open: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9875/3775 http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6348/3775 http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6372/3775 http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9776/3775

Comment: This question was put on hold for asking too opinion based question, then I edited it so it's not closed any more. 
Previous question was something along the lines recommend me a good resources. And I guess adjective "good" calls for opinion based comments.
Any way, that's that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phraseology is standardized by the ICAO (but countries can notify differences to the standard) in Annex 10 and other documents. The [ICAO quick reference guide](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/115.pdf) presents phraseology examples for various situations (taxi, approach, emergency,...). If you are interested in recommendations concerning radio communications in general (not just what directly concerns the pilot), Eurocontrol released a [European Action Plan for Air Ground Communications Safety](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/news/content/documents/nm/safety/agc-action-plan.pdf).

Many CAAs also have some form of phraseology reference manual available for free. The general procedures and the phraseology will be almost the same from one country to the next, but variations do occur.

- US:

  - The AIM has [a section dedicated to radio communications](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf#197) which details procedures, phraseology and provides general recommendations. Communication examples illustrate the general principles.
  - The FAA also published an [order prescribing ATC procedures and phraseology](http://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/atc.pdf) (but this is a very dry read. Not where I would start)
  - The [Instrument Procedures Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/media/FAA-H-8083-16.pdf) contains information regarding radio communication procedures specific to instrument flying (e.g. how to receive a clearance at a non-towered airport)
- EU:

  - Eurocontrol released [a guide to phraseology for GA pilots](http://www.atac.ca/web/images/Documents/Phraseology%20Guide%20for%20GA%20Pilot%20in%20Europe.pdf) describing good communication practices, phraseology for different flight phases and aviation acronyms. It also has pictures (picture books are always better ;-) ).
- UK:

  - The CAA release [a radiotelephony manual](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP41320Editionto4April2013_ISBN9780117928206.pdf) describing the phraseology for different flight phases with examples at the end of the manual. It also describes the differences between ICAO and UK radiocommunications procedures (eg FL ONE HUNDRED instead of FL ONE ZERO ZERO).
- France:

  - The SIA has a [phraseology training manual](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/asp_ssl/texteregle/texteregle-b.asp?ordre_0=3&langu=fr) with phraseology examples for each flight phase and for using different flight services (ATC, AFIS,...)
  - [The official text for radiotelephony](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dossier/texteregle/RADIOTEL_V2.pdf) with phraseology in French and English
- And many more...

---

Knowing the phraseology is one thing, but understanding what is being said on the radio can be quite difficult. If you want to practice listening to and understanding radio exchanges, you can find ATC recordings on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) or go to [LiveATC](http://www.liveatc.net) for ATC communications from all over the world.

Answer (score -2):

[VFR Communications for Idiots (West Wings)](http://www.westwingsinc.com/vfrcomm.pdf)

Radio Mastery for VFR Pilots Workbook (book)

[FAA safety circular on phraseology](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/libview_normal.aspx?id=17272)

The FAA holds regular safety seminars on communication

[ICAO Standard Phraseology](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/115.pdf)

[Phraseology Guide for GA Pilots in Europe](http://www.atac.ca/web/images/Documents/Phraseology%20Guide%20for%20GA%20Pilot%20in%20Europe.pdf)

Comment: This is right on the border of being a ["link-only answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) - I'm sure you can find a few more things to say besides "Here, click these!"

Comment: He asked for books and web sites. I gave him books and web sites.

Comment: @TylerDurden What makes these good compared to other resources? Any justification?